# Showing error when installing runing kivy desginer No module named 'kivy.adapters'

Tags: python, kivy

I had installed kivy from this YouTube video [How to install Kivy designer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_jv8KsYBrs) and when I run the designer with

```
python -m designer
```

I got an error

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.adapters'
```

or as shown in image.

[image: Error of Kivy Designer Run]

I also tried to uninstall all things and reinstall but the same problem every time.What should I do to solve this problem

I am on

- Processor: Intel Pentium Gold G5400
- Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit
- Python: 3.6.6 (64 bit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Problem: ModuleNotFoundError - `kivy.adapters`

```
     from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.adapters'
```

### Root Cause

- The `ListView` which is part of `ListAdapter` is deprecated and removed from Kivy version 1.11.0 onwards (including v1.11.1 and v2.0.0.dev0).
- The UI designer for Kivy is DEPRECATED. There is no current plan for
  continuing the development of Kivy Designer.

### Solution - using Kivy version 1.10.0

If you still want to take a test drive of Kivy Designer, do the following:

### OS: Windows - for Python 3

1. Make sure Pip, Virtualenv and Setuptools are updated with:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv setuptools`

2. Create a virtual environment with default Python interpreter:

`virtualenv --no-site-packages vKv1100Py3`

3. Enter the virtualenv, `source vKv1100Py3/bin/activate`
4. Install Cython, `pip install Cython==0.29.9`
5. Install Kivy version 1.10.0 in a virtual environment, `pip install kivy==1.10.0`
6. Install Python modules via pip: [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/), [Jedi](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/), [GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/)
7. Change directory to Kivy Designer folder, e.g. `cd kivy-designer`
8. Launch Kivy Designer, `python -m designer`

### OS: Linux/Ubuntu - for Python 3

1. Make sure Pip, Virtualenv and Setuptools are updated, `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip virtualenv setuptools`
2. Create a virtual environment with default Python interpreter,
   `virtualenv --no-site-packages vKv1100Py3`
3. Enter the virtualenv, `source vKv1100Py3/bin/activate`
4. Install Cython, `pip install Cython==0.29.9`
5. Install Kivy version 1.10.0 in a virtual environment, `pip install kivy==1.10.0`
6. Install Python modules via pip: [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/), [Jedi](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/), [GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/)
7. Change directory to Kivy Designer folder, `cd kivy-designer`
8. Launch Kivy Designer, `python -m designer`